# What's the meaning of "narrow" in "a narrow pretty greyhound of a woman"?

Tags: meaning, short-stories, joan-wickersham

The following is a sentence from [*The Tunnel, or The News from Spain* by Joan Wickersham](https://www.google.co.jp/books/edition/The_Best_American_Short_Stories_2013/m9HSWjTdxUsC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22a%20narrow%20pretty%20greyhound%20of%20a%20woman%22&pg=PA300&printsec=frontcover).

> Rebecca sees the wife around Cambridge, **a narrow pretty greyhound** of a woman, with a face that is at once anxious and arrogant.

I understand it means the woman is pretty but like a greyhound. But, what does "narrow" mean? Is she slim? Is her face thin? Or, is she narrow-minded?

Answer (score 1):

While agreeing with @Greybeard that this cannot be a reference to the woman’s relative openness of outlook, I’d suggest it means more than merely thin.

A person can be thin but not ‘narrow’ if they have a robust skeletal frame.

Taking ’narrow’ in conjunction with the ‘greyhound of a woman’ phrase, it conjures an image of a person who is not only thin, but fine boned and of narrow frame, with the lightness of movement that characterises a greyhound.

Under [Sheldon’s classification](https://www.britannica.com/science/ectomorph) of physique, she is likely to be an ‘ectomorph’.
[image: illustration of endomprph, mesomorph and ectomorph physiques, as line drawings of bald humans, vaguely male but devoid of genitalia]
The picture illustrates, from left to right, endomorph, mesomorph and ectomorph.

Answer (score 0):

As the narrator has only **seen** the wife, she cannot know whether she is narrow-minded. It must therefore mean small in breadth or width in proportion to length; lacking breadth, i.e. she had thin features.